# ios 5 twitter integration character length keeps varying

Tags: ios5, twitter, character, sharekit

Currently did ios5 twitter integration in my app using Sharekit framework  but I came across some strane issues of random max. character length shown in twitter window.

Sometimes I can see max character length as 106, sometimes its 95 and sometimes is 87.Its weird.

I understand that if we add images then it take around 21 characters + if we add URL by ourself then it reduces 21 character more. so at the end character length available for me should be 140-21-21 = 98.

But its not. any solution why its showing varying max character length ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twitter framework in iOS 5 recognizes URL's and knows they will be shortened to 20 chars. So an image and and url leaves you 140 - 21 - 20 = 99 chars. But if an URL is already shorter than 20 chars, it won't be wrapped to 20 chars, so http://apple.com will be just 16 chars and the tweet will be (140 - 21 - 16 =) 103 chars!

Besides that, are you sure the variations are not caused by differences in iOS < 5 and iOS5? 
Sharekit doesn't know [twitter is wrapping all URL's longer than 20 chars](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq) so it will tell you the URL needs the full amount of chars: 140 - 21 - URL_LENGTH = a lot longer.

Comment: for iOS5 < all ok. issue is only for iOS5. I have set 92 max. character length for iOS5 but still it shows negative value becuase it shows avaialable character length 87 in some cases. very strange.